# Form does not submit default value of Material UI DateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, typescript, react-redux, material-ui

I am working with React as my frontend and Ruby on Rails as my backend. I am trying to submit the value of my materialUI DateTimePicker through a form but it only works when I change the value of the default DateTimePicker but doesn't work when I just submit the form with the default value which is the current DateTime.
I tried displaying the formData when I am submitting my form and it shows that the value is indeed present but does not get inserted in the backend.

This is my DateTimePicker in the frontend

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <DateTimePicker
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    id="deadline_input"
                    type="date"
                    name="task[deadline]"
                    value={deadline}
                    className={classes.dateTimePicker}
                    {...params}
                  />
                )}
                value={deadline}
                onChange={(newDate: Date | null) => {
                  newDate && dispatch(setDeadline(newDate));
                }}
              />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

This is what I get when I console log the formdata and I can see my deadline value over here

```
(4) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ['task[title]', 'dfad']
1: (2) ['task[description]', 'fdfdsf']
2: (2) ['task[deadline]', '12/14/2021 12:43 am']
3: (2) ['task[tag]', 'dfad']
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

This is what happens on the backend server

```
Processing by Api::V1::TasksController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"task"=>{"title"=>"dfad", "description"=>"fdfdsf", "deadline"=>"12/14/2021 12:43 am", "tag"=>"dfad"}}
  TRANSACTION (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  Task Create (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("title", "description", "tag", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "dfad"], ["description", "fdfdsf"], ["tag", "dfad"], ["created_at", "2021-12-13 16:43:21.917824"], ["updated_at", "2021-12-13 16:43:21.917824"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (17.4ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb:20:in `create'
Completed 201 Created in 37ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 19.7ms | Allocations: 2182)
```

I also attached the output when I change the value of the DatePicker which works

```
(4) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ['task[title]', 'adfaf']
1: (2) ['task[description]', 'dsfdsf']
2: (2) ['task[deadline]', '12/01/2021 04:08 am']
3: (2) ['task[tag]', 'test']
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

```
Started POST "/api/v1/tasks" for ::1 at 2021-12-14 00:46:23 +0800
Processing by Api::V1::TasksController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"task"=>{"title"=>"adfaf", "description"=>"dsfdsf", "deadline"=>"12/01/2021 04:08 am", "tag"=>"test"}}
  TRANSACTION (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  Task Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("title", "description", "tag", "created_at", "updated_at", "deadline") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "adfaf"], ["description", "dsfdsf"], ["tag", "test"], ["created_at", "2021-12-13 16:46:23.468751"], ["updated_at", "2021-12-13 16:46:23.468751"], ["deadline", "2021-01-12 04:08:00"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb:20:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (12.2ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/tasks_controller.rb:20:in `create'
Completed 201 Created in 29ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 13.3ms | Allocations: 2175)
```

Just in Case you need my formSubmit Handler

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    formSubmit(e.target);
  };

  const formSubmit = async (formData) => {
    let data = new FormData(formData);
    console.log(Array.from(data));
      await fetch(api_url + "/tasks", {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        body: data,
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch(setTasks(tasks.concat([response])));
          dispatch(resetTask());
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the format of the date in the form data being sent to the api was the wrong format which was "MM/dd/yyyy" instead of "yyyy/mm/dd" and this resulted in the date being confused with the month and returned null when the date was greater than 12(Because the month cannot be greater than 12).

I just had to change the format of my dateTimePicker to "dd/MM/yyyy" instead of "MM/dd/yyyy" which is the default. Both "yyyy/MM/dd" and "dd/MM/yyyy" works find when sending the data to the database.

This is how I changed the format in the dateTimePicker

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <DateTimePicker
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    id="deadline_input"
                    type="text"
                    name="task[deadline]"
                    className={classes.dateTimePicker}
                    {...params}
                  />
                )}
                value={deadline}
                inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"
                onChange={(newDate: Date | null) => {
                  newDate && dispatch(setDeadline(newDate));
                }}
              />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Just had to add in this to the dateTimePicker

```
inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Just posting the answer so that it might help anyone facing the same problem later on